# Is there always a plane that covers the span of two vectors of any dimension(s)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two vectors $a$, $b$ of any dimension, is there always a plane that covers the span of both?

If so, what is the proof?

Comment: what is your definition of a plane?

Comment: Two dimensional flat surface that extends infinitely far.

Comment: No if the vector space has dimension less than $2$, otherwise yes.

Comment: But what is the proof for dimensions greater than or equal to 2?

Comment: Start with what it would mean for a plane to cover $span(a,b)$

Comment: As long as the two vectors are linearly independent, they span a two-dimensional subspace, i.e., a plane. The proof: a plane is *defined* as the span of two non-parallel vectors.

Answer (score 0):

I think that by any definition of plane, the set of all vectors of the form $\lambda a + \mu b$, where ($\dagger$) $\lambda,\mu\in\Bbb R$, must qualify as a plane.

($\dagger$ Assuming you’re talking about real vector spaces, that is.)

Comment: Unless $a$ and $b$ are parallel, of course.